# How to generate member just by clicking the drop-down from the toolbar, in Visual Studio, for C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

Coming from VB.NET I rarely use C# in Visual Studio so I know this might be a n00b question, but, in the Code Editor window when coding in VB you can just click the name of the method from the far-right drop-down and if it's a grayed-out item it'll auto-generate the member and take you to it; in C# however, when I do that, it just opens up that clicked item in the designer code window ...

Is there a way to replicate the same behavior of VB in the C# code window?

For reference, this is what I'm referring to:

[image]

Update in reference to one of my comments below:

[image]

Comment: I don't think you're right even about VB. I just checked out the navigation bar for a form in VB and it only showed methods that were actually implemented. Those in the designer file were greyed while in the user file and vice versa. As far as I'm aware, the only instance where VB will generate code from the navigation bar is handlers for events of the current class or its fields declared `WithEvents`. As there's no equivalent to `WithEvents` in C#, you can't do this in C#. You use the *Properties* window to generate event handlers for controls in C#, which you can do in VB as well.

Comment: @jmcilhinney hmmm, I know I'm probably getting my verbiage mixed around here (between subs, methods, handlers, etc... hey ... I'm self-taught :p) but I added a screenshot to the question to further depict what I mean; in VB if you click any method from the 2nd column (which C# doesn't even LIST in it's second column) you get a nice list of all available events for it. If you click any of them that doesn't already have a method in the code it'll generate it all (with all the proper arguments available, the `handles` clause, etc.), C# doesn't have any of that. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: @jmcilhinney (ran out of chars), Is that what you're referring to about `WithEvents`.

Comment: The middle column in VB is not methods. It's fields declared `WithEvents`. When you add a control in the designer, a field is automatically added to the designer code file and declared `WithEvents`. Add something like `Public WithEvents myDataTable As DataTable` to your form code and you'll see that appear in that drop-down too. There is no equivalent in C# so that functionality doesn't exist in C#. The C# `+=` operator is equivalent to `AddHandler` in VB and is the only way to attach event handlers.

Comment: `MenuStrips` and `StatusStrips` work exactly the same way in VB and C#. If there's any difference, I haven't noticed it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm not sure what's going on then, I'm in a C# project right now and in a menustrip I can't visually add menu items/subitems right on the menustrip itself; I only have the option to "edit items", which brings up the usual dialog to add/edit items. Same with a statusstrip.

Comment: That's not about the language. Your project is targeting .NET Core rather than .NET Framework. The WinForms designer for .NET Core doesn't quite have all the features of that for .NET Framework. When you create a project, you can select *.NET*, which will target .NET 5.0 by default and allow selection of other .NET Core versions, or you can select *.NET Framework*, which will target .NET Framework 4.8 and earlier. The .NET Framework option is what you are used to but you have selected the .NET option. If you want to switch, you will need to create a new project and then copy items across.

Comment: To see the difference...In C#  Form1.Designer.cs
`this.btnAddUser.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnAddUser_Click);`

In vb.net Form1.Designer.vb
`Friend WithEvents Button1 As Button`